# ExtJs: Use treeviewdragdrop and gridviewdragdrop together

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, treeview, extjs4.1, treegrid

I want to use integrate two Drag n Drop features of ExtJs 4.1.1

I want to drag nodes from a tree panel/grid into another tree grid.
Drag and drop feature should have the flexibility of [TreeViewDragDrop](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop) wherein I can drop a node into any parent node. Depth should matter.

But since I need to display my data in a [TreeGrid](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/example/tree/treegrid.html) format, I have to use [GridViewDragDrop](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop).

Due to this mismatch between the source and the destination I am not able to derive the required functionality of the two.

```
Here is a JSFiddle for this:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ATechieDiary/6Ad6b/2/

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Change both ptypes to 'gridviewdragdrop' and handle the depth manually in the plugin listener 'beforedrop' in the viewConfig.

```
viewConfig: {
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
        dragText: 'Drag and drop to reorganize'
    },
    listeners: {
        beforedrop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropHandlers) {

        //handle depth manually here

        }
    }
},
```